# Permanent redirect htaccess to a new domaine keeping a part of the URL as it is

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, iis

I never wrote any htaccess codnitions and the one by default dont give me enough to work with to get what I need,

I have a URL like : `http://domaineA.com/target:/to/be/removed/keep/this.ext`

And I want to redirect all URLs like this one to :

`http://domaineB.com/keep/this.ext`

I tried this, but didn't work:

```
//301 Redirect Entire Directory
RedirectMatch 301 http://domaineA.com/target:/to/be/removed(.*) http://domaineB.com/$1
```

**Update:**

I forgot to mention that the **/keep/this.ext** is **dynamic**, it represents all *files* of a my directory.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule as your very first rule in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?domaineA\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?target:/to/be/removed(/.*)?$ http://domaineB.com$1 [L,NE,R=301,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can put this in your .htacces or your virtualhost as below

```
Redirect permanent http://domaineA.com/target:/to/be/removed/keep/this.ext http://domaineB.com/keep/this.ext
```

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't mention that it concerns many files, so it has to be dynamic, because keep/this.ext is dynamic. I'll update my post.